# Sequencia de fibonnaci

Tags: python, fibonnaci

Dado a sequência de Fibonacci, onde se inicia por 0 e 1 e o próximo valor sempre será a soma dos 2 valores anteriores (exemplo: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34...), escreva um programa na linguagem que desejar onde, informado um número, ele calcule a sequência de Fibonacci e retorne uma mensagem avisando se o número informado pertence ou não a sequência.

IMPORTANTE:
Esse número pode ser informado através de qualquer entrada de sua preferência ou pode ser previamente definido no código;

#estou conseguindo fazer a sequencia, porem não consigo armazenar a sequencia gerada em uma lista para depois fazer a comparação com o valor de entrada :(

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
n = int(input())

a, b = 0, 1

while a < n:
    a, b = b, a + b

print(a == n)
```